# wrong output on eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, io

I open a file called "elenco" in order to write strings taken from keyboard input, but the files that I create through eclipse is empty, ideas why?
before this problem it regularly wrote on the file, but the output was full of strange symbols.

```
ds_file = open("elenco",O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
if (ds_file==-1) {
    perror("Errore nell'apertura del file");
}
```

With this I take the strings from keyboard

```
printf("Cognome >> ");
                        scanf("%s", cognome);
                        printf("Nome >> ");
                        scanf("%s", nome);
                        printf("Telefono >> ");
                        scanf("%s", telefono);
```

And with that I write the parameters in the file list, using as support a struct called contacts

```
int aggiungi(contatto a, int df){
int sizeWR;

lseek(df,0,2);

sizeWR=write(df, a.cognome, sizeof(a.cognome));
if(sizeWR==-1) return 0;
sizeWR=write(df, a.nome, sizeof(a.nome));
if(sizeWR==-1) return 0;
sizeWR=write(df, a.telefono, sizeof(a.telefono));
if(sizeWR==-1) return 0;

return 1; //contatto aggiunto correttamente
```

}

Any ideas to solve this problem? if you need more specifications just ask,the problem is really complex to explain in few lines.

EDIT: i explain shortly how application works: The server manages the file Elenco (creating) interacting with multiple clients from which I take (from the keyboard) name, lastname and phone number in order to create a phone book in Elenco.

For communication between client and server use a sockets.There are others functions for research and other stuff.

Here is whole code of my application:

http://pastebin.com/tzeUKd6C
http://pastebin.com/hsDu9S1H

Comment: did you try `fopen()`/`fprintf()`?

Comment: Your `scanf("%s", cognome);` reads into a variable named `cognome`. What's the relation between that variable and the `contatto a` that you use in e.g `write(df, a.cognome, sizeof(a.cognome));` ?

Comment: You need to post the whole code, because of, as shown, the variable a is not filled with scanfs. Post contatto struct, also.

Comment: Here is my whole code, divided into 2 Source file , named Server and Client:  

http://pastebin.com/tzeUKd6C
http://pastebin.com/hsDu9S1H

Comment: regarding this kind of line: 'scanf("%s", cognome);'  always check the returned value from scanf (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful (in this case, the returned value should be '1')   Most likely ALL the scanf calls after the first will fail because of the white space character (probably a newline) that is still in the stdin file stream  Suggest: if( 1 != scanf(" %20s", a.cognome) ) { // handle error }   Notice the leading space in the format string, so white space is consumed/skipped.

Comment: (continued) regarding this kind of line: 'scanf("%s", cognome);'  it seems the actual receiving array is 'a.cognome' not 'cognome'.     the user can overflow the input buffer 'a.cognome' because there is no limit on the number of characters.  suggest using a length modifier that is 1 less than the length of a.cognome.  the 'one less than' is to have room for the NUL byte appended by scanf()

Comment: looking at the postbin code.   this line: '#define perror(x) {puts(x); exit(1);}
' is a very bad idea for two main reasons.  1) perror() is system function, included in stdio.h.  (It prints the enclosed text + errno + the system message related to errno, to stderr)   2) the result is confusion in the human reader and a warning being raised by the compiler

Comment: in looking at the postbin code, placing all the sub functions before where they are called, to try and avoid using prototype statements has several shortcommings.   some of those shortcomings are: 1) maintenance is much more difficult.  2) calling a sub function from a different source file is much more difficult. (will need to have prototypes for that.)  suggest a header file that contains the prototypes and (perhaps) the macro definitions.  As projects get progressively bigger (real life projects are often hundreds of files) individual header files + prototypes will be required

Comment: I've changed partially my code following your suggestions, but the problem doesn't disappear, the file Elenco stay empty, I cannot write on it.